# remove titles, labels, legends from achartengine Android

Tags: android, charts, achartengine

I am trying to draw a chart(like below image) using achart engine library in android.

DESIRED_CHART.png

[image]

Here is what i achieved

CURRENT_CHART.png
[image]

Code to draw this is as below

```
private void drawChart(){
    int[] x = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 };
    int[] happyness = { 5,2,4,1,0,4,5,0};
    int[] energy = { 5,4,3,1,4,3,5,0};
    int[] strenth = { 2,0,1,3,2,4,3,0};
    int[] endurance = { 0,2,1,4,3,5,2,0};

    // Creating an  XYSeries for Income
    XYSeries happynessSeries = new XYSeries("Happyness");
    // Creating an  XYSeries for Income
    XYSeries energySeries = new XYSeries("Energy");
    // Adding data to Income and Expense Series
    XYSeries strenthSeries = new XYSeries("Strenth");
    XYSeries enduranceSeries = new XYSeries("Endurance");

    for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++){
        happynessSeries.add(x[i], happyness[i]);
        energySeries.add(x[i],energy[i]);
        strenthSeries.add(x[i],strenth[i]);
        enduranceSeries.add(x[i],endurance[i]);
    }

    // Creating a dataset to hold each series
    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    // Adding Income Series to the dataset
    dataset.addSeries(happynessSeries);
    // Adding Expense Series to dataset
    dataset.addSeries(energySeries);
    dataset.addSeries(strenthSeries);
    dataset.addSeries(enduranceSeries);


    // Creating XYSeriesRenderer to customize incomeSeries
    XYSeriesRenderer happynessRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    happynessRenderer.setColor(Color.parseColor("#f4ed21"));//chart border color
    happynessRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    happynessRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
    happynessRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
    happynessRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
    happynessRenderer.setFillBelowLine(true);
    happynessRenderer.setFillBelowLineColor(Color.parseColor("#bbf4ed21"));

    // Creating XYSeriesRenderer to customize expenseSeries
    XYSeriesRenderer energyRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    energyRenderer.setColor(Color.parseColor("#20bff2"));
    energyRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    energyRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
    energyRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
    energyRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
    energyRenderer.setFillBelowLine(true);
    energyRenderer.setFillBelowLineColor(Color.parseColor("#bb20bff2"));

    // strenth
    XYSeriesRenderer strenthRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    strenthRenderer.setColor(Color.parseColor("#f97b1d"));
    strenthRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    strenthRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
    strenthRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
    strenthRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
    strenthRenderer.setFillBelowLine(true);
    strenthRenderer.setFillBelowLineColor(Color.parseColor("#bbf97b1d"));

    // endurance
    XYSeriesRenderer enduranceRenderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    enduranceRenderer.setColor(Color.parseColor("#c68c4d"));
    enduranceRenderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    enduranceRenderer.setFillPoints(true);
    enduranceRenderer.setLineWidth(2);
    enduranceRenderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
    enduranceRenderer.setFillBelowLine(true);
    enduranceRenderer.setFillBelowLineColor(Color.parseColor("#bbc68c4d"));


    // Creating a XYMultipleSeriesRenderer to customize the whole chart
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer multiRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    multiRenderer.setXLabels(0);
    multiRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);              
    for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++){
        multiRenderer.addXTextLabel(i+1, mMonth[i]);            
    }       
    multiRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(50);
    multiRenderer.setYLabels(0);
    multiRenderer.setMargins(new int[]{0,0,0,0});

    multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(happynessRenderer);
    multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(energyRenderer);
    multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(strenthRenderer);
    multiRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(enduranceRenderer);

    multiRenderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);
    multiRenderer.setZoomEnabled(false, false);
    multiRenderer.setZoomEnabled(false, false);

    // Creating an intent to plot line chart using dataset and multipleRenderer
    mChart =(GraphicalView) ChartFactory.getLineChartView(getBaseContext(), dataset, multiRenderer);

    llChart.addView(mChart);

}
```

**first and last x Axis points values (Mon feb 3 and Mon Feb 9) are cutting.** I am struggling to show these values as DESIRED_CHART.png

**How to remove this black background behind the Xaxis Values?**

Answer (score 6):

To change background color

```
multiRenderer.setMarginsColor(Color.GREEN);
```

and give margins to show whole x Axis points values text

```
multiRenderer.setMargins(new int[]{0,40,0,40});
```

To hide title

```
multiRenderer.setChartTitle("");
```

To hide legends

```
multiRenderer.setShowLegend(false);
```

where `multiRenderer` is `XYMultipleSeriesRenderer` .

Comment: thanks man . How can i remove the black background (behind x axis labels)? And first/last points of X axis are cuttin off. Any help regarding this.

Comment: Everything I answered use margins .